# distribute and sync multiple dedicated servers in unreal 5

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-5

I hope this is a good place to ask my question

I'm using unreal engine 5.

My game would be only one map and I want to all of clients play in one session.

I want to have unlimited numbers of clients.

Is it possible to create more than one dedicated servers that are in sync with each other?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a good reason why most games split their players among sessions. You can see the alternative in EVE Online: when too many players decide to show up in one star system at once, the whole thing slows down. Sharing the load between servers only gets you so far, since the communication between those servers is vastly slower than communication within a single machine, and each client still needs to receive and render updates about all the other players nearby. Your game may have special traits that help mitigate this, but you have not told us enough about your game for a reader to know.

Comment: Suffice it to say, this could be an immense engineering challenge. If you had a full studio of industry experts and massive server infrastructure at your fingertips, maybe you could pull off something no one else has before. But if your level of expertise and resources are such that you're asking here, then I'd say it's likely that this goal will be out of your reach for now. Instead, it may help to take a step back and consider why you want all players in one session: maybe we can find clever game design ways to achieve that target experience in a way that scales well between server sessions.

Comment: @DMGregory I don't have a specific game in mind. this is only a challenge for me and I want to do it. In general, if there is a way, guide me please

Comment: There is no "general" solution to this problem for a real-time game. Any potential solution would be highly specific to the kinds of interactions that need to be mediated by the server for a particular game to function, and the play patterns it needs to support. Even then, "unlimited" numbers of clients would remain out of reach, like most infinities. The best you can hope for is "a large number". The larger the number, the more you need to sacrifice to support realtime play, since there's only so much computation and communication you can fit into a unit of time.